# Better way of getting values from table without looping 300 queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query and a loop written that lists all the rows from a mysql table ("records") formatted in a HTML table.

One of the fields is "subject_id" which is an integer. I also have a table named "subjects" which corresponds to the same "subject_id" in the records table. Only two fields are in the "subjects" table, is an auto-index ID integer and a varchar(1024) for the subject title.

The value that returns from the "records" table is an integer. I want to perform a lookup on the integer from the "records" table for each row to output the text equivalent from the "subject_id" field.

My first notion, the kindergarten way, would be to throw in another query within the loop, effectively increasing my number of queries from 300 to 600 to load the page (no pagination is needed).

What would be a better way of this "sub query" aside from adding 300 more queries?

**Edit:**
I'm pulling the data from the table using a while loop and echoing my variable $r_subject (from: $r_subject = mysql_result($result,$a,"subject");). The value returned from the initial records table is INT. I want to take the $r_subject and then check it against the SUBJECTS table to get the string name associated with that INT id.

Comment: Where does the number 300 come from?  You are matching rows between tables `RECORDS` and `SUBJECTS` using `subject_id`, but how are you selecting rows from `RECORDS`?

Comment: There's currently about 300 records in the RECORDS table. I'm pulling it by SELECT * FROM `records` because I'm using data from all fields to populate a HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you need without seeing code, but from what I gather, you have 2 tables, one has the ID, the other has the text, so you would want to use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

The second thing is, you'll want to look at whether or not you really need 300 queries in the first place. That's a lot of queries to run and you should only need to run that many queries when you're running a bulk insert/update or something of that nature; other than that, you most likely could reduce that number substantially.

Comment: Ultimately the **JOIN** is what I needed to just learn and deal with the curve. Thank you Francis.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    A.*, 
    B.title 
from 
    records A, 
    subjects B 
where 
    B.subject_id = A.subject_id
```

That's a single query that will produce all of the data you need for your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      subjects.SubjectTitle,
      records.whateverFieldYouWant,
      records.AnyOtherField
   from
      records
         join subjects
            on records.subject_id = subjects.subject_id
   where
      records.subject_id = TheOneSubjectYouWant
```

but can't confirm without actual structure of tables and some sample data displayed showing proper context of what you are expecting out